# How to check if a text contains any of the words in a list in Golang?

Tags: string, go

I'd like to check if there is any spam words in user submitted text. So here is the function that I've written:

```
func TextHasSpamWords(text string, spamWords []string) bool {
    removePunctuation := func(r rune) rune {
        if strings.ContainsRune(".,:;", r) {
            return -1
        } else {
            return r
        }
    }
    text = strings.Map(removePunctuation, text)
    sort.Strings(spamWords)
    for _, word := range text {
        for _, sapmWord := range spamWords {
            if word == sapmWord {
                return true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I get `mismatched type rune and string` at `word == sapmWord`. 
I know this is because `removePunctuation` returns runes (aka int32) which can not be compared with string (unit8). But removing punctiuations is indispensible for the function to work so I'm wondering how can I fix this? Or perhaps there is a more idiomatic way to do so?

Comment: You can try https://github.com/vikramjakhr/profanity-filter-server
It's implemented using goroutines for parallel processing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to compare a letter vs a string.

When you are doing `for _, word := range text`, it's not word, it's `letter`. If you want the words, you have to split the string in a slice of words with `textArr := strings.Split(text, " ")` (split by whitespace)

```golang
func TextHasSpamWords(text string, spamWords []string) bool {
    removePunctuation := func(r rune) rune {
        if strings.ContainsRune(".,:;", r) {
            return -1
        } else {
            return r
        }
    }
    text = strings.Map(removePunctuation, text)
    textArr := strings.Split(text, ` `)
    sort.Strings(spamWords)
    for _, word := range textArr {
        for _, sapmWord := range spamWords {
            if word == sapmWord {
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: While this solves the mismatch issue, it is not a good solution. Because for example if `apple` is in the list of spam words, and user posts `apples` in the text, it is not flaged by the function.

Comment: Then, you can use `strings.Contains` -> `if (strings.Contains("word", "sapmWord"))` to check if `apples` contains `apple`

Comment: Actually, I would change the `strings.Split()` to this: https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Fields. 
The `strings.Fields()` function will handle all Unicode whitespaces.

Answer (score 3):

Consider using a map for the lookup

```
lookupSpam := make(map[string]bool)
for _, v := range spamWords {
    lookupSpam[v] = true
}
```

Then instead of

```
for _, word := range textArr {
    for _, sapmWord := range spamWords {
        if word == sapmWord {
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

something like this can be used

```
for _, word := range textArr {
    _,found:=lookupSpam[word]
    if found {
       return true
    }
}
```

If you are repeatedly checking the same set of words then set up the map once and reuse it

Comment: What difference does this usage of maps make in terms of lookup speed?

Comment: a map is O(1) and a loop as your original code suggested is O(n)  See https://adrianmejia.com/most-popular-algorithms-time-complexity-every-programmer-should-know-free-online-tutorial-course/#.WucLR8N8SmE.hackernews

Comment: Great, but then how deal with mutations of spam words, like when `apple` is `lookupSpam` map but user posts `apples` (and this also should be flagged).

Comment: Your original doesn't deal with a fuzzy match or stemming.  My suggestion deals with your original request, if you'd like to expand the scope, ask another question....